# How much mail will be lost if I only support SMTPS?

Tags: smtp, smtps

If I configure my locally hosted SMTP server to only accept SMTPS connections (secure SMTP port 465/587), how much mail will I lose because sender(s) don't support sending on SMTPS?

Are the major mail providers fully complaint of SMTPS on 587?

Comment: Don't host a mail server at home. It won't work if your ISP has blocked port 25; most mailservers are _not_ yet using SMTPS in my experience.

Comment: I didn't get "home" from his question. I have a lot of Customers who have locally hosted SMTP but none of them are at "home".

Answer (score 5):

Port 587 is the submission port for clients to submit mail for delivery. Other SMTP servers won't send email to you on port 587-- they use port 25.